# How many integers $\{xy \colon 1\le x\le y\le 2x\}$?

Tags: number-theory

Find the asymptotic upper density of the set $\{xy\, \colon\, 1\le x\le y\le 2x\}$.

---

In other words, let $S$ be the set of all integers which can be expressed as $xy$, for some positive integers $x,y$ such that $x\le y\le 2x$. Then evaluate
$$
\limsup_{x\to \infty}\frac{|S\cap [1,x]|}{x}
$$

Comment: Type Kevin Ford divisors into the web, and see whether the links that come back help you to answer this question.

Comment: Tried it yet???

Comment: The distribution of integers with a divisor in a given interval , Annals of Math. (2) 168 (2008), 367-433, Kevinf Ford [Corollary 3]: it is an atomic bomb, but yes it works, very thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The asymptotic upper density is zero.

If $n = xy$ with $1 \leq x \leq y \leq 2x$ then $y^2 \leq 2n$, whence $n$
is contained in the $\sqrt{2n} \times \sqrt{2n}$ multiplication table.
Hence $|S \cap [1,X]| \leq M(\sqrt{2X})$, where for any $N$ 
we denote by $M(N)$ be the number of distinct entries in the $N \times N$ 
multiplication table (i.e. the size of $\{xy \mid 1 \leq x,y \leq N \}$.
It is known that $M(N) / N^2 \rightarrow 0$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$.
Therefore $|S\cap[1,X]| \,/\, X \rightarrow 0$ as claimed.

According to [these lecture notes by Carl Pomerance](http://math.dartmouth.edu/~carlp/sumproductboston.pdf),
the result $M(N) / N^2 \rightarrow 0$
is a theorem of Erdős from 1955 that follows easily from
a 1917 result by Hardy Ramanujan on the "normal order" of the 
$\Omega$ function.  Recall that $\Omega(k)$ is the number of prime factors
of $k$ *with multiplicity*, so $\Omega(\prod_i p_i^{a_i}) = \sum_i a_i$
(e.g. $\Omega(k)=3,2,2,1$ for $k=8,9,10,11$).  Thus
$\Omega(xy) = \Omega(x) + \Omega(y)$.  But Hardy and Ramanujan proved
that for each $\epsilon>0$ the set of integers $k$ for which
$$|\Omega(k) - \log\log k| > \epsilon \log\log k$$ has density zero.
Hence asymptotically 0% of the $N^2$ pairs $(x,y)$ with $1 \leq x,y \leq N$
yield $xy$ with $\Omega(xy) < (2-2\epsilon) \log \log N$. 
Hence asymptotically 0% of the $N^2$ pairs $(x,y)$ with $1 \leq x,y \leq N$
yield $xy$ with $\Omega(xy) < (2-2\epsilon) \log\log N$, 
while 0% of the numbers in $[1,N^2]$ have
an $\Omega$ value greater than $(1+\epsilon) \log\log N^2$.
But the loglog function grows so slowly that
$$\log\log N^2 = \log\log N + \log 2,$$
so for large $N$ (and $\epsilon < 1/3$) the $\Omega$ value cannot be
both $\geq (2-2\epsilon) \log\log N$ and $\leq (1+\epsilon) \log\log N^2$.
This proves the density-zero claim.

I found the link to the Pomerance notes in **Joe Silverman**'s recent answer
to [Mathoverflow Question
31663](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31663) from five years ago.  According to those notes, as of 2012
Kevin Ford has the sharpest results known about $M(N)$ for large $N$ 
(as **Gerry Myerson** hinted in his comment here, and also wrote in his
answer to that Mathoverflow question); but it is still an open
problem to obtain an asymptotic formula for $M(N)$.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a complete answer, but I found an upper bound <s>and evidence that it is sharp</s>.

Let $S(x):=\{xy : x \leq y \leq 2x \} $ and $M(z) := \vert S \cap [1,z] \vert$.

<s>It seems that if $S(x) \cap S(y) \neq \emptyset$ then $x=y$. If this is true, my bound on $M(z)$ seems to be sharp, but if it is false, the approximation still gives an upper bound.</s> **As Peter Košinár pointed out, $72 \in S(6) \cap S(8)$. However, it seems that a similar technique might be able to count duplicates.**

Suppose the above condition. Note: $\vert S(x) \vert = x+1$, $\min S(x) = x^2$, and $\max S(x) = 2x^2$.

Let $x:=w^2$ and $w \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then the $x$'s such that $S(x)$ intersects $[1,z]$ are exactly $x \in [1,w]$.

$S(w)$ only has one element in the range, namely $z$.

For the purposes of an upper bound, suppose that all of the elements in the rest of the sets intersect $[1,w]$.

Thus our bound $f(z) = 1 + (w-1) + (w-2) +\dots+ 2 = w(w-1)/2$, the $(w-1)$-th triangular number.

From this, we may derive $M(z) = \mathcal{O}(w(w-1)/2) = \mathcal{O}((z-\sqrt{z})/2)$ and thus $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{M(z)}{z} \leq \frac{1}{2}$

My main evidence is a proof that the above holds if $y:=x+1$. 
Suppose $S(x) \cap S(x+1) \neq \emptyset$. 
Then $\exists a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $x(x+a)=(x+1)(x+1+b)$, $0 \leq a \leq x$, and $0 \leq b \leq x+1$.

Expanding this equation gives $ax = x(2+b)+b+1$ and rearranging gives $x(a-2-b)=b+1$. Because $a$ and $b$ are integers, we have $b+1 \bmod x \equiv 0$.

Because $b$ is less than or equal to $x+1$ and congruent to $0$ modulo $x$, $b$ must be equal to $x$. Thus we may substitute $x$ for $b$ and get $x(a-2-x)=1+x$, which, solved for $a$ is $a=(1+3x+x^2)/x$. Thus, because $a \in \mathbb(Z)$, $1+3x+x^2 \bmod x \equiv 0$ and $x$ must be equal to $1$.

Additionally, consider the following small values:
$$
S(1) = \{1,2\}\\
S(2) = \{4,6,8\}\\
S(3) = \{9,12,15,18\}\\
S(4) = \{16,20,24,28,32\}\\
S(5) = \{25,30,35,40,45,50\}\\
S(6) = \{36,42,48,54,60,66,72\}\\
S(7) = \{49,56,63,70,77,84,91,98\}
$$
(Note that $M(25)=13$ and $M(36)=18$.)

I tried generalizing the condition in a similar way to how I proved the above case, but it requires more tools than I have. Also, the assumption that $S(w-1)$ was entirely in the range should be improved for a complete proof.

This is a definitely an interesting problem and I hope this (still) helps.

Comment: $S(6)$ and $S(8)$ both contain $72$.

Comment: Thank you. No wonder, then, why I had trouble trying to extend the example to y=x+2.